# How can I change how Ktor encodes spaces in query parameters?

Tags: rest, kotlin, ktor

By default, Ktor encodes spaces as `+` in query parameters, which I understand is the general convention. However, the API I have to work with is not particularly well-designed, and so it only accepts `%20` as a space, even in query parameters. Is there any way I can tell Ktor to always encode spaces as `%20` no matter the context?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't change the logic of encoding space in every context. The only thing you can do is encode query parameters manually:

```
val builder = URLBuilder().apply {
    encodedParameters = ParametersBuilder().apply {
        append("name", "some value".encodeURLParameter(spaceToPlus = false))
    }
}

println(builder.buildString())
```